# Solving one-zero linear programming

Tags: ampl

I have a model about one-zero linear programming, when I use AMPL, I declare variables as binary type, but when I solved it, my results have many numbers not is 0,1.

```
var X{1..7,1..21,1..4} binary;
```

I think the type of variable: integer, binary not doing in AMPL

When I solved it, my results such as: `X[1,5,6]=0.55555`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [mixed-integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) solver such as CPLEX or Gurobi to get an integer solution. The default AMPL solver is MINOS which relaxes integrality and issues a warning such as:

```
MINOS 5.51: ignoring integrality of 10 variables
```